# how to select quarterly data in sql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

how do i get my data by quarter? i have this html to let the user select his/her desired quarter.

```
<select name="quarterly">
  <option value="2015-01">Quarter1</option>
  <option value="2015-04">Quarter2</option>
  <option value="2015-07">Quarter3</option>
  <option value="2015-10">Quarter4</option>
</select>
```

how should i use QUARTER() function and returns my data by quarter of the year?

this is my query im using CI.

```
$quarter_val = $this->input->get('quarterly');
$this->db->select('ainoheads, aittlperweight, aittlperclass')
         ->from('main_data')
         ->where('QUARTER(ai_ordDate)', $quarter_val);
```

Comment: Please give us your table structure.

Comment: just let say these are the columns "ai_id, ainoheads, aittlperweight, aittlperclass, ai_ordDate"

Comment: ainoheads, aittlperweight and aittlperclass are int and ai_ordDate is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i read it right on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter then you have to do

```
SELECT ainoheads, aittlperweight, aittlperclass FROM main_data WHERE QUARTER(ai_ordDate) = "$quarter_val";
```

Comment: it returns the data, but im not sure if these data are the selected quarters i'll check it first then i'll mark this as answer thanks!.

Comment: Well i tested if on my phpMyAdmin before i posted the awser and i also selected the CUARTER of the date and all worked fine.

Comment: The MySQL `QUARTER()` functions will return a number between 1 and 4.  In the OP, the `$quarter_val` will never match this, unless you also make the change suggested by @sg-.  Please state your assumptions.

Comment: Of corse it hast to be a number between 1 and 4 that is clear isn't it?

Comment: yes this query will work if i'll change the value of option like @sg recommend tnx!

Comment: w8 what if i want 2014 quarterly data or 2015 quarterly data and so on?

Comment: Then you can use YEAR(date) = 2015 for example

Answer (score 3):

QUARTER returns an integer between 1 and 4.  You probably want this:

```
<select name="quarterly">
  <option value="1">Quarter1</option>
  <option value="2">Quarter2</option>
  <option value="3">Quarter3</option>
  <option value="4">Quarter4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just making your change above will solve the problem, without having to change the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the selected quaterly option and then extract the numerical quarter from it:

```
$quarter_val = $this->input->get('quarterly');
$newformat = date('Y-m',$quarter_val);
$currMonth = date("m", $newformat);
$currQuarter = ceil($currMonth/3);

$this->db->select('ainoheads, aittlperweight, aittlperclass')
         ->from('main_data')
         ->where('QUARTER(ai_ordDate)', $currQuarter);
```

You SQL query looks fine and I have not changed it.

Answer (score 0):

to get the quarters in a specific year i do this

first i change the value like this

```
<select name="quarterly">
   <option value="1,2015">Quarter1</option>
   <option value="2,2015">Quarter2</option>
   <option value="3,2015">Quarter3</option>
   <option value="4,2015">Quarter4</option>
</select>
```

(i loop the select to get the other years)

and then at the back-end i do this code.

```
$quarter_val = $this->input->get('quarterly');
$explode_quar = explode(",",$quarter_val); //returns Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2015 )

$this->db->select('ainoheads, aittlperweight, aittlperclass')
         ->from('main_data')
         ->where('YEAR(ai_ordDate)', $explode_quar[1])
         ->where('QUARTER(ai_ordDate)', $explode_quar[0])
         ->get();
```

thanks for the help @hans, @tim and @sg..

Answer (score 0):

The quarter_val 1 will bring month january, february and march

`$quarter_val = 1;
$query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Starting_Date,'%M %Y') as month
FROM student
WHERE QUARTER(Starting_Date)='$quarter_val' AND YEAR(Starting_Date)='$year'") or die(mysqli_error($link));`